# Recducing the size of Jquery Autocomplete cross in textbox

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a jquery autocomplete textbox. When I enter the text in the box, a cross appears at the end whos size is larger than expected.

[image]

I have added the code as below which removes the cross button completely.

```
#countBox::-ms-clear {
    display:none;
}
```

But is there any way which can reduce the size of the cross that appears.

Comment: you must add complete js css  code that is relevant to your problem so that anyone can help you out. we dont know what classes other than this class is applied to your element, plus the cross would be appearing via `javascript` and the `css` properties can be over written via `JS` so your class would have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether you use bootstrap or only CSS for your styles. I had similar issue and fixed it as below.

```css
#Search::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
    position:relative;
    right:10px;  
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" name="Search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

By changing the height and width, you can set the size of the cross mark. Also try this http://jsfiddle.net/5XKrc/3/. This is where i got idea of fixing my similar issue.